# Clipping shapefiles with different CRS in QGIS 2

Tags: coordinate-system, clip, qgis-2

In QGIS 2.18.22 I have to different vector-shapefiles and I would like to clip the overlay.

Unfortunately, the shapefiles did originally not have the same CRS so I saved them in the desired CRS (EPSG:4326, WGS 84). After that, I opened a completely new project (EPSG:4326, WGS 84) and opened the new shapefiles (OTF is turned off).

However, there is still no overlap between both shapefiles, but I can zoom to each of the shapefiles individually. Clipping is of course still not working.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve that problem? I checked the similar questions but I did not find any solution for my problem.

Comment: One (or both) of your shapefiles is not saved as EPSG:4326 - look at the coordinates when you are zoomed in to each layer one of them will not be between -180 - 180, -90, 90 that is the wrong one.

Comment: Do you mean the coordinate field at the bottom margin next to the scale? Do I then simply have to save it again?

Comment: Yes I mean those coordinates, no - you need to go back to the start with that file and fix it

Comment: You are right - that was the problem. Thanks!!